# Burn the rubber [ball]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, retag-request, burninate-request

Can we burn [ball](/questions/tagged/ball)? What purpose does it serve? All the good or decent questions are also tagged [collision-detection](/questions/tagged/collision-detection), so why have [ball](/questions/tagged/ball)?

Comment: ["Do not taunt Happy Fun Ball."](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7gzDC-2ZO8I)

Comment: Aw, poor [ball]...

Comment: Oh, questions about drawing balls. Do we need [unicorn] tag for questions about drawing unicorns?

Comment: There's a [bounce](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bounce) tag too. Blech.

Comment: The [tag:rolling] also doesn't appear to group meaningfully related questions together.

Comment: @thegrinner bounce at least kinda makes sense, if it were relating to bouncing emails and such.

Comment: @neminem It should be something like [email-bouncing]

Comment: Can any moderators help here? This tag is still getting questions asked with it. There were two in November, but the questions were by low rep users (less than 10 rep). So maybe we don't need a full burning, but just a manual retagging effort.

Comment: Fellow mates!! @ColeJohnson i need your help over here meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/209089/remove-business-tag im almost out of AMMo!

Comment: @ŁukaszL. you mean this ? [tag:unicorn]

Comment: @AsshO.Lee looks like we got some [tag:business] to take care of ;)

Comment: @ColeJohnson that has a lot of [tag:business] to taken care off and i need some back up! :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I retagged all the posts with appropriate tags if required.

[image: All hail Trogdor!]

Answer (score 1):

[ball](/questions/tagged/ball) has zero questions tagged with it since I checked today, so for the next automatic cleanup this tag would be automatically burninated. I also don't see any use for it because it has no tag-wiki on it. Hopefully it will never come back.

So it's safe to assume that this tag has been ***BURNINATED***.

Comment: That's because @ZaheerAhmed retagged them all right before you checked :P

Comment: oh i guess im pretty much late on the ball partey!

Comment: @ColeJohnson i know that Correct spelling of Party, I'm just making fun of it making it sound like a slang "Parteey" or "Partey", but it means party.